# Passing Objects to a function

Tags: php

I had a function that escapes data before performing SQL statements. Now Problem is I have 4 databases, So how can I pass database object to function.

```
function escape($what) 
{
global $db;

foreach ($what as $variable => $value)
{
    if (is_string($value) || is_numeric($value))
    {

        $GLOBALS[$variable] = $db->real_escape_string();
    }
    else
    {
        $GLOBALS[$variable] = $value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _database object_ ?

Comment: `$GLOBALS`?  Have you heard of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Comment: It's time to go for PDO friend.

Comment: To escape sql statements, its recommended to use prepared statements.
Al the escaping is done for you that way so you dont have to invent the wheel again. Look for mysql::prepare(); On php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another parameter to your function:

```
function escape($db, $what)
```

And change the calls to the function.